# My navbar won't work in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am in the process of learning how to use bootstrap and was watching some simple how-to videos on YouTube. My code is this.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">

</div>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

For some reason the navbar isn't showing up at all. I have all the right css and js files called, I just can't figure out why it won't load.

Comment: I don't see your `bootstrap.css` being loaded in anywhere. You, also, don't need to include both `bootstrap.min.js` and `bootstrap.js`; just use the min file. Your HTML code is correct otherwise. http://www.bootply.com/mCcizYqcC3

Comment: Also, it looks like you have the Boostrap Javascript file loaded twice. bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap.js are the same thing. you only need to include one of them.

Comment: @Marcelo You can't see it for some reason because it wouldn't pop up, but it's there. Should I only use the bootstrap.min.css also or both that and bootstrap.css?

Comment: @KJStahl Just the min one usually. The two files do the exact same thing (as far as the browser is concerned) but the min file takes up less space and will transferred to the user faster.

Comment: What do you mean "Wouldn't pop up?" Can you post the part of your code that calls your CSS file?

Comment: @Marcelo Won't pop up means that the black navbar that should be across the screen isn't appearing on my browser. I'm using NetBeans if that means anything.
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css"  rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Well, your HTML is correct so it is probable something is not being loaded (the most likely culprit being bootstrap.css). The best course of action is to load your site and check for any errors in the console. Beyond that, with the current information, there is not much else that we can do without simply speculating.

Comment: @Marcelo so I think I found the out the problem. I was going through it with a friend and I think the code in NetBeans is not up to date. Basically it was giving me multiple errors about how the class isn't found, and it wasn't even there, even though I pulled the template from the bootswatch. I am going to try and just update the bootstrap.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files were out of date. Make sure the files are the most current ones. Just download the new ones and replace it with the old ones.